# List view scrolls past top widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following where the List view is created fine under the text widget.

But if I scroll up, it scrolls past the top text widget.

Same issue if I use ListView.Builder. At first thought this persisted only on IOS platform.

But now noticing the same issue in Android too. I have condensed the implmentation such that

You could copy this entire block of code and paste it in https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab-web

and recreate issue to see it. (Takes a while for it to render though).

Can I please get some advice on what I am doing wrong pls?

Experiencing the same in Emulators and actual mobile devices. Thanks.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyAppOne());
}

class MyAppOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Text('The List scrolls behind this text instead of stopping under it'),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  // hard coded values to simplify. accountTitles is just used to iterate
                  // based on its size which is length 30. Issue exists in this example.
                  children: accountTitles.map((e) => ListTile(
                    tileColor: Color(0xff1B223E),
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.home,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      'Some title',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.home,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ),).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<String> accountTitles = [
    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',  '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
];
```

Comment: A suggestion, You could direct people to use [dart pad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true) vs CodeLab which has a bunch of docs and other distracting elements :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Solution :  Use `Material` wrap `ListView` or Use `Material` wrap `ListTile`
Source code of `ListTile` describe https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/1fd2f7c400a719931e9fa181a2dd19f1756a0c95/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/list_tile.dart#L731

```
class ListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  ...
  /// Requires one of its ancestors to be a [Material] widget.
  const ListTile({
```

and because `ListTile` use `InkWell`, The `InkWell` widget must have a `Material` widget as an ancestor. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html

[image]

code snippet

```
Expanded(
    child: Material(
      child: ListView(
```

or

```
Material(
      child: ListTile(
        tileColor: Color(0xff1B223E),
```

working demo `Material` wrap `ListView`

[image]

full code with `Material` wrap `ListView`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyAppOne());
}

class MyAppOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                  'The List scrolls behind this text instead of stopping under it'),
              Expanded(
                child: Material(
                  child: ListView(
                    // hard coded values to simplify. accountTitles is just used to iterate
                    // based on its size which is length 30. Issue exists in this example.
                    children: accountTitles
                        .map(
                          (e) => ListTile(
                            tileColor: Color(0xff1B223E),
                            leading: Icon(
                              Icons.home,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            title: Text(
                              'Some title',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            trailing: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<String> accountTitles = [
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the expected behavior?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyAppOne());
}

class MyAppOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Text('The List scrolls behind this text instead of stopping under it'),),
              SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                  // hard coded values to simplify. accountTitles is just used to iterate
                  // based on its size which is length 30. Issue exists in this example.
                  accountTitles.map((e) => ListTile(
                    tileColor: Color(0xff1B223E),
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.home,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      'Some title',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.home,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ),).toList(),
                ),
                  )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<String> accountTitles = [
    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',  '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
];
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused "stopping under it", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Have a look at the gif posted by @chunhunghan. That is what I was looking to achieve.

Comment: ahh...that not really "stopping under it". Anyway glad you found the answer.